# MySQL select to put every field on a new line

Tags: mysql, select

For this question, let's say I have a table with 3 columns and 5 rows.

```
First, Last, Age  
bill,  smith, 40  
bob,   smith, 45  
ann,   smith, 25  
johnny, Carr, 30  
donna, jones, 21
```

How can I get MySQL to output each field on a new line? Like this.

```
bill  
smith  
40  
bob  
smith  
45  
ann  
smith  
25
```

... and so on

I tried `\G` but it won't work in Pancakes.
I tried concat with `\n` but that is not giving me new lines either.
Both `\G` and concat `\n` seem kind of 'hacky' to me, plus, I need to add several more conditions and nesting, so `'\G'` and `'concat \n'` won't really work anyway.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: But why? Oh, the humanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is `union all`:

```
select lastname as col from table union all
select age from table union all
select firstname from table;
```

Now, some caveats.  First, the first subquery defines the column name and type.  Presumably that is some sort of string.  MySQL will convert `age` (which is presumably a number) to the right type.  However, if age were first, you would probably get errors.

Second, there is no guarantee of the ordering without an `order by`.  So, if you are expecting the results in a particular order, you would do that.

Third, each of the `select` subqueries is going to do a scan on the underlying table.  With 5 rows, this is a non-issue but there are more efficient ways to do this when tables have lots and lots of rows.

Note:  I'm assuming that "as a new line" means "as a separate row in the query result set".

EDIT:

If you want things in a particular order, you need an `order by`.  There is no such field, so you need a subquery to add one.  Here is a reasonable method:

```
select col
from (select lastname as col, lastname, age, firstname, 1 as ordering from table union all
      select age, lastname, age, firstname, 2 from table union all
      select firstname, lastname, age, firstname, 3 from table
     ) t
order by lastname, age, firstname, ordering
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest accomplishing this using `UNION ALL` as well.  Definitely not the "prettiest" thing with larger tables, but it should get the job done.

Comment: Hmmm, it's giving me all the first names first, then all the last names, then all the ages.  It's close to what I need, but not exactly.  Can you tweak it so I get one person's first, last, age together?